# When can you move the verb at the end of a sentence to the beginning?

Tags: word-order

I have a friend from Switzerland with whom I text almost exclusively in German. I asked her how many people are coming to a small gathering she's hosting and she replied with this:

> **Zugesagt haben bis jetzt 6** (inkl. uns), es kann aber sein, dass noch mehr kommen.

The clause in bold is what I'm wondering about. I have only studied German from 2015-2018 in college, but I distinctly remember being taught that the Perfekt form of a verb **must** go at the end of the clause. So if I were the one typing this message it would read

> 6 Leute haben bis jetzt **zugesagt**,...

with "zugesagt" at the end. I asked her about it her about it and the first rephrasing that came to her mind was instead

> Es haben bis jetzt 6 zugesagt,...

She agrees that with no context, phrasing 1 sounds weird and she would rather use phrasing 2 or 3. However in context she claims that 1 puts emphasis on "zugesagt" and considers the "6 Leute" as being more passive in the situation. But this was only her best guess. So my question is **when is one allowed to move the Perfekt form of the verb to the beginning of the sentence?** Does it have to do with phrasing 3 sounding more natural with this sort of dummy "es", so one can somehow replace the es with the ending verb to just get rid of it? I'm sure I was lied to sometimes in my college German courses in order for things to be made simpler, but I would like to know what the logic behind this construction is.

Comment: https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/progr@mm/5296

Comment: The first item in a main clause is its topic. You can put **anything** there.

Comment: In German grammar terminology, it's the *Vorfeld*. Almost any sentence part can be put there, except the finite verb of course. Modal particles also cannot be placed there.